# Can an iPhone app generate web clips?

Tags: iphone, app-store, web-clips

The safari browser lets you add an icon to the home screen as a bookmark to whatever webpage you happen to be on. I would want to do that same thing, but in an app I develop. So basically, the user would launch the app, do a bunch of stuff and somewhere along the way, a web clip would be created and pushed to their home screen (with their consent of course). Is this possible, or is it a feature exclusive to the Safari browser? It seems like this sort of thing could be done, but it also seems like it could be viewed as spam and therefore a reason for Apple to reject the app outright. Is this sort of thing feasible? If so, I would be very thankful for a link on where I could read up on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely that the iOS app security sandbox would allow an app to directly add web pages to the home screen.

Best bet might be to upload the webpage to some site, and then launch Safari with a URL to the webpage on that site, after requesting that the user manually "clip" that site using Safari.

Comment: Well that's a bit disappointing, but understandable I suppose. It would drive a lot of people away if they launched an app and an hour later, pressed the button to find their home screen cluttered with random garbage that wasn't there before. Well, thanks for the clarification.